# Flagged articles' comments don't show the article name on flag history page

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-flags, flag-history, articles

I flagged a comment from an article as "No longer needed" and this is what I see in my [flag history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current):

[image: A flagged comment from an article without showing where it's from (the article name is just an empty space).]

I expect to be able to see where this comment is from, e.g.:

[image: A flagged comment from an answer showing the answer score and the question's title.]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! We'll fix it and update this post when that's done.

Comment: @JD-Stack can you confirm this is fixed? It seems so.

Comment: Confirming, this is fixed.